# Windows Server and Updates causing 404 Error?

Tags: asp.net, windows-server, windows-update

I was on the fence of which section to post this in but I think I came to the correct place. Apologies upfront if I was wrong!

I have a Windows Server 2008, hosting a small ASP.NET Web Application (IIS7) for almost a year now.  Through-out the year, I notice that randomly on what seems to be, random pages, myself and others will get the 404 Forbidden / Access is denied error.

**Every time, the solution has been to run windows updates on the Windows Server 2008 machine which is hosting the ASP.NET web applications.**

On simular issues, I have seen suggestions that setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in the web.config will resolve 404 issues.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

What is the reason for windows updates, on my Windows Server 2008, to cause this 404 issue on my ASP.NET Web Application? Also, will this code resolve my issue? Of course many would say to test it out, but the error is rare and could take a week, month / months to arise.

Comment: Have you checked the event log on the machine to see if anything shows up when this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem trying to install the hotfix(s).  I went here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368  and updated the webconfig that is noted and that corrected my issue with the 404

Comment: This allowed you to install the hotfix? Or simply adjusting the webconfig fixed your issue?

Answer (score 2):

For a real fix, apply this hot fix :

http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows%207/WindowsServer%202008%20R2/sp1/Fix305889/7600/free/407288_intl_x64_zip.exe

Read [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368) about problem / solution

This article describes a update that enables certain Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.0 or IIS 7.5 handlers to handle requests whose URLs do not end with a period. Specifically, these handlers are mapped to "*." request paths. Currently, a handler that is mapped to a "*." request path handles only requests whose URLs end with a period...

**runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" is a bad idea.**

Comment: It said, this windows update is not applicable to your computer

Comment: In the event log I get, "Windows update  could not be installed because of error 2147943623" when trying to install the 64 bit version, and "Windows update  could not be installed because of error 2149842967" when trying to install the 32 bit version

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 X64

Comment: I extracted 407288_intl_x64_zip.exe and ran the MSU file as administrator.  I have restarted the server and still run into the same issue "Windows update is not applicable to your computer"

Comment: I'm on service pack 1, perhaps KB980368 is already included and this is not the underlying issue to my problem?

Comment: Am I doing something wrong. What do you mean by try the hotfix "directly" I have tried the first provided link, as well as the others found on the microsoft support link you provided

Comment: With "directly" I mean the same as you did, run as admin 407288_intl_x64_zip.exe . I don't understand why you get that error. I used this fix on 4 servers without problems, and after restart the IIS routing has been fixed